# How to get data from variable array length?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$ItemID = 'a62442e2-ca1f-4fd1-b80d-0d0dc511758e'; 
$GET_FreeTextFields = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\ItemExtraField($connection);

    $FreeTextFields = $GET_FreeTextFields->filter("ItemID eq guid'$ItemID'", '', '' );
    $FreeTextFields01 = array();
    $FreeTextFields02 = array();
    foreach($FreeTextFields as $GET_FreeTextFields){
        $FreeTextFields01[] = $GET_FreeTextFields->Value;
        $FreeTextFields02[] = $GET_FreeTextFields->Number;
    }
    print_r($FreeTextFields01);
    print_r($FreeTextFields02);
```

This outputs:

```
Value Array
(
    [0] => 390
    [1] => 804715
    [2] => WW001
    [3] => WHT/WHT/WHT
    [4] => 39/42
    [5] => 804715         WW00139/42
    [6] => 3pk Quarter Socks
)
Numbers Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 10
)
```

What this needs to output:
What i want if i use the first output so with 6 values in the array:

```
$FreeTextField01 = null
$FreeTextField02 = null
$FreeTextField03 = 390
$FreeTextField04 = 804715
$FreeTextField05 = WW001
$FreeTextField06 = WHT/WHT/WHT
$FreeTextField07 = 39/42
$FreeTextField08 = 804715          WW00139/42
$FreeTextField09 = null
$FreeTextField10 = 3pk Quarter Socks
```

But with other $ItemID, it can also output:

```
Value Array
(
    [0] => 10100153
    [1] => 2007
    [2] => 350
    [3] => 804082
    [4] => WW006
    [5] => WHT/NNY/OXGM
    [6] => 35/38
    [7] => 804082         WW00635/38
    [8] => 0,00138857
    [9] => Champion 3pk Quarter Socks
)
Numbers Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```

What i want is that if a variable is not in the numbers list so 1-10, setting it to empty, and if the numbers is in the numbers array setting that number to the corresponding value variable. For example the number at [0] is 1 then set the variable $FreeTextField1 to $NumbersArray[0]->Value.

I keep making all kinds off loops but i just get stuck at the fact that the array length changes so that [6] can be the number 10 at one $itemID, but at another $ItemID, the number can be 6.

I tried researching this but I don't even know what I have to type in google to find this problem, that's why I'm describing it here.

edit i tried describing it a second time:
Yeah I'm having problems describing what i want, so let me try again. I get two arrays as output one with numbers that correspond with place it stands, as example you have FreeTextField0 thru FreeTextField10. What i tried to do is `if (Numbers[0] == 0){ $FreeTextField0 = Value[0]}`, but then I get the problem that Numbers[0] can be 3 or something else because if FreeTextField1 is empty i don't get a null value but nothing.

What i want if i use the first output so with 6 values in the array:

```
$FreeTextField01 = null
$FreeTextField02 = null
$FreeTextField03 = 390
$FreeTextField04 = 804715
$FreeTextField05 = WW001
$FreeTextField06 = WHT/WHT/WHT
$FreeTextField07 = 39/42
$FreeTextField08 = 804715          WW00139/42
$FreeTextField09 = null
$FreeTextField10 = 3pk Quarter Socks
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but I'm quite sure variable variables is not the best solutution

Comment: Yeah I'm having problems describing what i want, so let me try again. I get two arrays as output one with numbers that correspond with place it stands, as example you have FreeTextField0 thru FreeTextField10. What i tried to do is ` if (Numbers[0] == 0){ $FreeTextField0 = Value[0]}`, but then I get the problem that Numbers[0] can be 3 or something else because if FreeTextField1 is empty i don't get a null value but nothing.

Comment: Can you please post the exact output you actually want?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I put the output i want in the post

Comment: Do you always want to generate _10_ variables (`$FreeTextField01` - `$FreeTextField10`) regardless of how many values are in the data array?

Comment: @waterloomatt Yes exactly, and if there is no number corresponding to the variablename then it has to be set to null. So if there is no number 1 then variable `$FreeTextField01 = nulll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after but I have to say that I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. You really should not dynamically create variables in your script. To me, it is a serious code-smell and I think you should evaluate your design here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b245a0218ce174e68508139872f394def5409b05

```
<?php

// Test case
$values = [
    '390',
    '804715',
    'WW001',
    'WHT/WHT/WHT',
    '39/42',
    '804715         WW00139/42',
    '3pk Quarter Socks'
];

$numbers = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10];

// Flip the $numbers array and then use the keys to find the corresponding values in the $values array
$intersection = array_unique(array_intersect_key($values, array_flip($numbers)));

// Fill in the missing keys and use `null` as the value
$output = $intersection + array_fill_keys(range(1,10), null);

// Sort the final output by the keys
ksort($output);

// Format the keys to match FreeTextField{00}
$output = array_combine(
    array_map(function($k){ return 'FreeTextField'.str_pad($k, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); }, array_keys($output)),
    $output
);

// Use the extract function to bring all those array keys + values into the symbol table. 
// You can now use $FreeTextField01 - $FreeTextField10
extract($output);

var_dump($output);
```

**UPDATE**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/244c4f1ed45db398c48b8330c402b375eb358446

```
<?php

// Test case
$input = [
    ['Value' => '390', 'Number' => 3],
    ['Value' => '804715', 'Number' => 4],
    ['Value' => 'WW001', 'Number' => 5],
    ['Value' => 'WHT/WHT/WHT', 'Number' => 6],
    ['Value' => '39/42', 'Number' => 7],
    ['Value' => '804715         WW00139/42', 'Number' => 8],
    ['Value' => '3pk Quarter Socks', 'Number' => 10],
];

$intersection = [];

foreach ($input as $config) {

    $value = $config['Value'];
    $number = $config['Number'];

    $intersection[$number] = $value;
}

// Fill in the missing keys and use `null` as the value
$output = $intersection + array_fill_keys(range(1,10), null);

// Sort the final output by the keys
ksort($output);

// Format the keys to match FreeTextField{00}
$output = array_combine(
    array_map(function($k){ return 'FreeTextField'.str_pad($k, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); }, array_keys($output)),
    $output
);

// Use the extract function to bring all those array keys + values into the symbol table. 
// You can now use $FreeTextField01 - $FreeTextField10
extract($output);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Yeah almost but the biggest problem is that if the number is 1 then the value needs to be set to a specific variable. So if number[0] is 1 then $FreeTextField**01** needs to be Value[0]

Comment: Hmmm. Just re-read your question for the 5th time. Still not sure what you want. Going to delete this answer until it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Posted new answer based on updated question details.

Comment: @waterloomaat Thank you for taking the time and trying to understand my question, but when i try your code. There are seven input values, but the output only has four variables filled `["FreeTextField03"]=>
  string(11) "WHT/WHT/WHT"
  ["FreeTextField04"]=>
  string(5) "39/42"
  ["FreeTextField05"]=>
  string(25) "804715         WW00139/42"
  ["FreeTextField06"]=>
  string(17) "3pk Quarter Socks"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `${$var}` 
If you want to see a doc about this type of var you can see it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: i changed the link to the english version so any one who is not speaking that language can read it